# Node.js server not correctly serving files

Tags: node.js, http

I am attempting to serve an html file to a browser that also loads a simple javascript file via `<script src="./script.js"></script>`. When I run `server.js` and I check the port it is supposed to be serving to, the `script.js` doesn't load. What am I doing wrong?

Server code

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8080

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(404)
      res.write('Error:File Not Found')
    } else {
      res.write(data)
    }
    res.end(); 
  })
})

server.listen(port, (error) => {
  if(error) {
    console.log('Something went wrong', error)
  } else {
    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port)
  }
})
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Today's Date</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, you are only serving index.html. To serve other files, you need to modify your code to check, which file is requested, before serving it.

The naive example on how to accomplish it:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 8080
var path = require('path')


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
  let url = new URL(req.url, 'https://example.org/'); 
  // req.url is a relative address, 
  // but URL only works with relative addresses, if we provide
  // "base" address. So we provide it a fictional one,
  // it doesn't really matter in our case.
  let fileToRead = url.pathname
  if (fileToRead=== '/') fileToRead = '/index.html'
  fs.readFile(path.resolve(`./static/${fileToRead}`), function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(404)
      res.write('Error:File Not Found')
    } else {
      res.write(data)
    }
    res.end(); 
  })
})

server.listen(port, (error) => {
  if(error) {
    console.log('Something went wrong', error)
  } else {
    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port)
  }
})
```

Please note that the files should now be stored in static directory. It's never a good idea to expose your code to the users of your web-resources ;)

Comment: Thanks for the great info. How do you create a static directory. Do you just name it "static"?

Comment: yup :) Or you could name it otherwise, but you'd need to edit your code accordingly.